# JSONLint not working please find the error

Tags: jsonlint

```json
{
    "processImages": true,
    "processAnimatedMedia": true,
    "similarityTolerance": 5,
    "onUserReply": "reportBot",
    "reposts": {
        "smallScore": 50,
        "smallScoreRepostDays": 10,
        "mediumScore": 500,
        "mediumScoreRepostDays": 50,
        "largeScore": 1000,
        "largeScoreRepostDays": 100,
        "topScore": 3000,
        "approveIfOverRepostDays": false,
        "reflairApprovedReposts": false,
        "actionRepostsIfDeleted": false,
        "action": "remove"
    },
    "removeBlacklisted": {},
    "removeBrokenImages": {}
},
"removeBlacklisted": {},
"removeBrokenImages": {},
"removalMessage": "Sorry BRO!, your post has been removed as it appears to be a     repost.",
"allTimeTopRemovalMessage": "Sorry BRO!, your post has been removed as it appears to be a repost of an all-time top post.",
"fullRemovalMessage": "Hey {{author}}, your post has been removed as it appears to be a repost. Here's a link to the previous submission by you: {{last_submission_link}} posted {{time_ago}} ago.",
"actionAll": false

}
```

it shows - Error: `Parse error on line 21: ...kenImages": {} }, "removeBlackli ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', got ','`

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? You closed the last `}` on line 21, which means `EOF` (end of file).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "ADD_KEY_HERE": {
        "processImages": true,
        "processAnimatedMedia": true,
        "similarityTolerance": 5,
        "onUserReply": "reportBot",
        "reposts": {
            "smallScore": 50,
            "smallScoreRepostDays": 10,
            "mediumScore": 500,
            "mediumScoreRepostDays": 50,
            "largeScore": 1000,
            "largeScoreRepostDays": 100,
            "topScore": 3000,
            "approveIfOverRepostDays": false,
            "reflairApprovedReposts": false,
            "actionRepostsIfDeleted": false,
            "action": "remove"
        },
        "removeBlacklisted": {},
        "removeBrokenImages": {}
    },
    "removeBlacklisted": {},
    "removeBrokenImages": {},
    "removalMessage": "Sorry BRO!, your post has been removed as it appears to be a     repost.",
    "allTimeTopRemovalMessage": "Sorry BRO!, your post has been removed as it appears to be a repost of an all-time top post.",
    "fullRemovalMessage": "Hey {{author}}, your post has been removed as it appears to be a repost. Here's a link to the previous submission by you: {{last_submission_link}} posted {{time_ago}} ago.",
    "actionAll": false
}
```

ADD_KEY_HERE please replace accordingly, then it will work.